# ejabberd 501 feature-not-implemented

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I am new of xmpp. Now I want to get roster, but a 501 error returned.

IQ:

```
<iq type="get" to="xmpp" id="foobar"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"/></iq>
```

Response:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="xmpp" to="zhangjiuzhou@xmpp/23675463291407297410678734" type="error" id="foobar">
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"/>
    <error code="501" type="cancel">
        <feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error>
</iq>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `to` attribute in the request.  Your request is likely getting routed somewhere you don't expect.